# Why is ADT calling code that the doc specifies throws an UnsupportedOperationException?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

My XML layout in res/layout/edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView 
  android:id="@+id/GridView01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:numColumns="2">
<TextView
  android:text="Person's Name"
  android:id="@+id/PersonName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView
  android:text="Person's Points"
  android:id="@+id/PersonPoints"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</GridView>
```

When I try to switch from "edit.xml" to "Layout", I see this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not
supported in AdapterView
```

I checked the documentation for AdapterView, and this is expected behavior.  Why, then, does ADT expect it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to add two `TextView`s to it in the xml. Don't do that. The views for any `AdapterView` have to come from the adapter.

You'll have to put your `TextView`s in another Layout that contains your `GridView` as well. Layouts you can use are: FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, TableLayout, or implement your own. I think what you are trying to do is have two buttons on top of a `GridView` that you will be providing an Adapter that will fill it.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The two `TextView`s will be the same size because of the `layout_weight` attribute. The following `GridView` will take up the rest of the space.

If all you were trying to achieve was having the two `TextView`s next to each other but being the same size then just use the second `LinearLayout` with the horizontal orientation.

Comment: So <?xml blah?> <ViewGroup blah> <GridView blah /> <TextView blah /> <TextView blah /> </ViewGroup>?

Comment: Actually, I think I want TableLayout, not GridView.  This looks like a bit of a fiasco as it is.  Thanks.